# Can I reuse function decalartion in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Lets say some external library or typescript itself did declare function such as

```
declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

Is it possible to reuse this declaration for different function without copy paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for something like this (*pseudo code*):

```
declare function fetch(
  input: RequestInfo | URL,
  init?: RequestInit
): Promise<Response>;

declare function myFetch = fetch;
```

No, that's not possible. But you can copy the type information in a dynamic way with the utility types [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) which gives you the exact same signature.

```
declare function myFetch(
  ...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>
): ReturnType<typeof fetch>;
```